# How to make grep for a regex that appear multiple times in a line

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression

I want to grep a regex. The pattern I am searching for may appear multiple times in a line. If the pattern appeared many times, I want to separate each occurrence by a comma and print **the match only** not the full line in a new file. If it did not appear in a line I want to print **n.a.**

Example. I want to use this regex to find numbers in the pattern: [12.123.1.3].

```
grep -oh "\[\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\]" 'filename'
```

input file (input.txt)

```
blabla [11.335.2.33] xyuoeretrete [43.22.11.88] jfdfjkfbs [55.66.77.88]
blabla [66.223.44.33]
foo bar
blabla [1.2.33.3] xyuoeretrete [42] bla[1.32.2.4]
```

intended result in a new file (output.csv):

```
11.335.2.33,43.22.11.88,55.66.77.88
66.223.44.33
n.a.
1.2.33.3,1.32.2.4
```

**Note: I use Ubuntu**

Comment: As you already see from answers, it is quite far from grep knowledge. grep can select lines, but you want text processing... you need a "real langue" for that.

Comment: Are you asking for dotted-octet decimal IPv4 address notation? With each of the 4 numbers taking a value between 0 and 255?

Answer (score 4):

With `perl`:

```
perl -lne '
  if (@ips = /\[(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})\]/g) {
    print join ",", @ips;
  } else {
    print "n.a.";
  }'
```

Or using the regexp for dotted-quad-decimal IPv4 addresses from `Regexp::Common` (`libregexp-common-perl` package on Debian-based systems such as Ubuntu):

```
perl -MRegexp::Common=net -lne '
  if (@ips = /\[($RE{net}{IPv4})\]/g)
    print join ",", @ips;
  } else {
    print "n.a.";
  }'
```

With `-n`, input can be given either on stdin or read from files whose paths are given as extra arguments or from the output of some commands if passed arguments like `some commands|`. `perl`'s `print` prints to stdout by default, which from your shell you could redirect into a file with redirection operators such as `>`, `>>` (append), or `1<>` (like `>` except the file is not truncated first, and is opened in read+write mode), and possibly more depending on your shell.

You can also add the `-i` option for the output to end up replacing the contents of the input files (whose paths must then be given as arguments).

Here, to take the input from a file called `input.txt`, and overwrite or create a `output.csv` file with the output:

```
< input.txt perl... > output.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU awk for the FPAT:

```c
awk -v FPAT='\\[([0-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}\\]' -v OFS=, '
{
    $1=$1; print (gsub(/[][]/, "")?$0:"N/A")
}' <infile >output
```

or with any POSIX awk (which all supports the `{x,y}` RE intervals):

```c
awk '
{
    bkup=$0;
    gsub(/\[([0-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}\]/, "|")
    gsub(/[][()\\.{}?+*$^]/, "\\\\&")
    n=split(bkup, tmp, $0)
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
        if(tmp[i]!=""){
            gsub(/[][]/, "", tmp[i])
            printf ("%s", (sep?",":"") tmp[i])
            sep=","
        }
    }; print (sep?"":"N/A"); sep=""
}' <infile >output
```

---

Output is written into the file *`output`*.

```
$ cat output
11.335.2.33,43.22.11.88,55.66.77.88
66.223.44.33
N/A
1.2.33.3,1.32.2.4
```

Note that your input should not contain `|` and `&` characters for the second approach.

---

Same code with inline explanation:

```c
awk '
{
    #backup from the current record
    bkup=$0;

    #replace desired pattern all with "|" characters 
    #to build regexp patterns of everything other than our desired pattern
    gsub(/\[([0-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}\]/, "|")

    #escape all regexp operators except "|"
    gsub(/[][()\\.{}?+*$^]/, "\\\\&")

    #split the original record (from bkup) into tmp on regexp
    # from the result of the first gsub() above
    n=split(bkup, tmp, $0)

    #loop through the splitted fields on the tmp array
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++){

        #if the current field is not empty
        if(tmp[i]!=""){

            #remove the ], [ characters from it
            gsub(/[][]/, "", tmp[i])

            #and print it (will add comma when it is the second or the next one)
            printf ("%s", (sep?",":"") tmp[i])

            #set comma as the field seperator when at least one field was printed
            sep=","
        }

    #print "N/A" in case there was no field and var "sep" did not set above
    # and then unset the "sep" var
    }; print (sep?"":"N/A"); sep=""

}' <infile >output
```

Answer (score 1):

Executable awk  file `filter.awk`:

```c
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
{
    ret = ""
    line = $0
    while (match(line, /\[([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}\]/) > 0) {
        if (ret != "") {
            ret = ret ","
        }
        ret = ret substr(line, RSTART, RLENGTH)
        line = substr(line, RSTART + RLENGTH)
    }
    if (ret != "") {
        print ret
    }
}
```

Executed like that:

```bash
./filter.awk filename
```

Comment: when I tried to run I get: `sudo: ./filter.awk: command not found`. I used `sudo` I my terminal path is the same of the `filter.awk`

Comment: The `filter.awk` file must be executable with command like : `chmod 755 filter.awk`.
Check if the `awk` path is really `/usr/bin` with this command : `which awk`. Fix shebank (first awk file line) if necessary.
When you use sudo, like crontab, it's better to use absolute path.

Comment: @randomname use `sudo` sparingly and only in very specific situations when absolutely required for very specific reasons. This isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl in sed mode (-p), (-l) shall remove LF (\n) from every record read and also append to every record printed.

```bash
perl -plse '
  $_ = "@{[/\[\K\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}(?=])/g]}" || "n.a.";
' -- -\"=, file
```

---

GNU sed in extended regex mode (-E)

```bash
sed -E '
  s/\[([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3})]/\n\1\n/g

  y/\n_/_\n/
    s/[^_]*_([^_]*_)/\1/g
    s/_?[^_]*$//
  y/\n_/_,/

  /./!c n.a.
' file
```

---

Using awk with progressive matching of the regex

```bash
_m0="n.a." \
awk -v OFS=, '
BEGIN {
  msg = ENVIRON["_m0"]
  _d = "[[:digit:]]{1,3}"
  fmt = sprintf("%s%%s([.]%%s){%%d}%s", "[[]", "[]]")
  ip_re = sprintf(fmt, _d, _d, 3)
}
{
  t=$0;$0=""
  for (i=1; match(t,ip_re)>0; i++) {
    $i = substr(t, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2)
    t = substr(t, RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
!NF{print msg};NF' file
```

---

Output:

```
11.335.2.33,43.22.11.88,55.66.77.88
66.223.44.33
n.a.
1.2.33.3,1.32.2.4
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

No value-checking:

```perl
raku -ne 'if m:g/ ( \d**1..3 )**4 % "." / { $/.join(",").put } else {"n.a.".say};'
```

OR

```perl
raku -ne 'm:g/ ( \d**1..3 )**4 % "." / ?? $/.join(",").put !! "n.a.".say;'
```

Sample Input:

```
blabla [11.335.2.33] xyuoeretrete [43.22.11.88] jfdfjkfbs [55.66.77.88]
blabla [66.223.44.33]
foo bar
blabla [1.2.33.3] xyuoeretrete [42] bla[1.32.2.4]
```

Sample Output (both examples):

```
11.335.2.33,43.22.11.88,55.66.77.88
66.223.44.33
n.a.
1.2.33.3,1.32.2.4
```

At least in Perl-family languages, what you're asking for is a `match`, not grep. hence use of the `m/.../` match operator, made 'global' as in `m:g/.../` to return multiple instances of the match [which differs from grep, which returns the full element (such as a line, etc.), *containing* a match].

Briefly, clusters of 1-to-3 digits ( `\d**1..3` ) are searched for, with these digits `**4` repeated 4 times, and having `% "."` a period between each instance, and this regex match is searched for globally (`m:global` or `m:g`), meaning to get all instances of the match per element (line, etc.), not just the first match. First example: if found (`if`) out`put` the match contained in the `$/` match variable, `else` say `n.a.`. Second example: same match conditional used in Raku's ternary operator, i.e. `condition ?? True !! False`. Thus if the conditional is `??` (True), out`put` the match contained in the `$/` match variable, if the conditional is `!!` False say `n.a.`.

---

Below WITH value-checking:

```perl
raku -ne 'if m:g/ ( \d**1..3 <?{ $/ < 256 }> )**4 % "." / { $/.join(",").put } else {"n.a.".say};'
```

OR

```perl
raku -ne 'm:g/ ( \d**1..3 <?{ $/ < 256 }> )**4 % "." / ?? $/.join(",").put !! "n.a.".say;'
```

Sample Input: same as above

Sample Output (both examples):

```
43.22.11.88,55.66.77.88
66.223.44.33
n.a.
1.2.33.3,1.32.2.4
```

Immediately above, Raku code is shown that checks each 1-to-3 digit cluster to ensure it is an integer less than `256`. The additional regex element, `<?{ $/ < 256 }>` , is a positive assertion containing a `{...}` code-block that checks if `$/` match-variable is less than 256. Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60857440/7270649).

https://raku.org